# Is the word "essentially" an adjective in phrase "essentially nonlinear phenomena"?

Tags: adjectives, adverbs

I need help. the word "essentially" seems to be an adjective in the phrase "essentially nonlinear phenomena". Is it? but "essentially" could only be an adverb! I'm confused and need help. Thanks a lot.

Comment: An adverb modifying "nonlinear" (or "nonlinear phenomena" depending on context.)

Comment: ***essentially*** here is just a weaker alternative to other adverbial qualifiers such as ***very, completely*** (modifying adjectival ***nonlinear***, which itself modifies the noun ***phenomena***).

Comment: It is rare for an -ly word to be anything but an adverb except in case like lonely, only, surly, etc.

Comment: There are those who consider that adjective-modifiers and adverb-modifiers should be put in distinct classes. In the traditional analysis, 'plumb' has to become an adverb in 'plumb loco', as does 'pretty' in 'pretty good',  'blind' in 'blind drunk', 'drop-dead' in 'drop-dead gorgeous', 'stony in 'stony broke', 'filthy' in 'filthy rich',  'lead-pipe' .... // But an example sentence could be ambiguous: 'essentially' may be modifying the independent clause _or_ the adjective. _They are essentially nonlinear phenomena. Essentially, they are nonlinear phenomena._ They are _essentially nonlinear_.

Comment: @BillJ: it it was modifying *nonlinear phenomena*, it would be an adjective, not an adverb.

Comment: No: adverbs can modify NP's (but not nouns). The salient interpretation of the OP's example is that "essentially" is modifying "non-linear", but modifier in the NP can't be rule out.

Comment: Aaron. Please give the entire sentence containing the phrase. Context makes a lot of difference in English. Also, do you have a link to the original text?

Answer (score 3):

No, *essentially* is an adverb, modifying the adjective *nonlinear*.

This means we say things like:

> We will discuss essentially nonlinear phenomena

but

> Will will discuss the essential nonlinearity of that system.

Answer (score 0):

*Essentially* may be seen as an adverb, modifying *are/is*. It modifies the manner of being.

In this case if we wrote “These are essentially nonlinear phenomena” we would mean that the manner of being of the phenomena is that they are nonlinear.

Such a statement in a mathematical or scientific context draws attention to the fundamental nature of the phenomena. The use of *essentially* implies that they are in essence nonlinear: that is to say that nonlinearity lies at the heart of their being and defines their nature. Nonlinearity is not merely lightly descriptive but is essential to their nature.

> Essential = basic to the nature of someone or something
>
> [Cambridge dictionary](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/essential)

Comment: It would be helpful to all if the down-marker were kind enough to explain their viewpoint. Mere negativity helps no-one, least of all the questioner.